# If I assume that the variables are positive number, should I put absolute value when taking them of out of a square root?

Tags: radicals

If I assume that the variables are positive number, should I put absolute value when taking them of out of a square root?

like if I assumed that u is a positive number and I have square root u to the power 2. Should it be |u| or u?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that $u$ is positive, then $|u|=u$, so you can write either $u$ or $|u|$ and nothing should change.